# Runtime error in c++ when analysing time

Tags: c++, runtime, analysis, timing, ctime

I'm trying to check how much time passes with each 3 solutions for a problem, but sometimes I get a runtime error and can't see the passed time for 3rd solution, but sometimes it works. I think the solutions.h file is correct but i put it here anyway.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "solutions.h"
using namespace std;

    int main()
{
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
int* input1 = new int[10000];
int* input2 = new int[20000];
int* input3 = new int[40000];
int* input4 = new int[80000];
int* input5 = new int[100000];

for(int i = 0; i<100000; i++)
{
    input1[i]= rand();
    input2[i]= rand();
    input3[i]= rand();
    input4[i]= rand();
    input5[i]= rand();
}
int* output1= new int[1000];

double duration;


clock_t startTime1 = clock();
solution1(input1,10000,1000,output1);
duration = 1000 * double( clock() - startTime1 ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout << "Solution 1 with 10000 inputs took " << duration << " milliseconds." << endl;

startTime1 = clock();
solution2(input1,10000,1000,output1);
duration = 1000 * double( clock() - startTime1 ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout << "Solution 2 with 10000 inputs took " << duration<< " milliseconds." << endl;

startTime1 = clock();
solution3(input1,10000,1000,output1);
duration = 1000 * double( clock() - startTime1 ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout << "Solution 3 with 10000 inputs took " << duration << " milliseconds." << endl<<endl<<endl;



return 0;
}
```

And the solutions.h is

```
#ifndef SOLUTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define SOLUTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#include <cmath>

void solution1( int input[], const int n, const int k, int output[] );
void solution2( int input[], const int n, const int k, int output[] );
void solution3( int input[], const int n, const int k, int output[] );

void swap( int &n1, int &n2 ) {

int temp = n1;
n1 = n2;
n2 = temp;
}

void solution1( int input[], const int n, const int k, int output[] ) {

int maxIndex, maxValue;
for( int i = 0; i < k; i++ ) {
    maxIndex = i;
    maxValue = input[i];
    for( int j = i+1; j < n; j++ ) {
        if( input[j] >= maxValue ) {
            maxIndex = j;
            maxValue = input[ j ];
        }
    }
    swap( input[i], input[maxIndex] );
    output[i] = input[i];
}
}

int partition( int input[], int p, int r ) {

int x = input[ r ], i = p - 1;
for( int j = p; j < r; j++ ) {
    if( input[ j ] >= x ) {
        i = i + 1;
        swap( input[i], input[j] );
    }
}
swap( input[i+1], input[r] );
return i + 1;
}

void quickSort( int input[], int p, int r ) {

int q;
if( p < r ) {
    q = partition( input, p, r );
    quickSort( input, p, q - 1 );
    quickSort( input, q + 1, r );
}
}

void solution2( int input[], const int n, const int k, int output[] ) {

quickSort( input, 0, n - 1 );
for( int i = 0; i < k; i++ ) {
    output[i] = input[i];
}
}

int partition2( int input[], int a, int p, int r ) {

int x = a, i = p - 1;
for( int j = p; j < r; j++ ) {
    if( input[ j ] == x ) {
        swap( input[ j ], input[ r ] );
    }
    if( input[ j ] >= x ) {
        i = i + 1;
        swap( input[i], input[j] );
    }
}
swap( input[ i + 1 ], input[ r ] );
return i + 1;
}

void quickSort2( int input[], int p, int r ) {

int q;
if( p < r ) {
    q = partition2( input, input[ r ], p, r );
    quickSort2( input, p, q - 1 );
    quickSort2( input, q + 1, r );
}
}

int findMin( int n1, int n2 ) {

if( n1 <= n2 )
    return n1;
else
    return n2;
}

int select( int input[], int n, int k, int start, int end, int flag ) {

if( n <= 5 ) {
    quickSort2( input, start, end );
    return input[ start + k - 1 ];
}
int i = start, numGroups = (int) ceil( ( double ) n / 5 ), numElements, j =     0;
int *medians = new int[numGroups];
while( i <= end ) {
    numElements = findMin( 5, end - i + 1 );
    medians[( i - start ) / 5] = select( input, numElements, (int) ceil( (   double ) numElements / 2 ), i, i + numElements - 1, 1 );
    i = i + 5;
}
int M = select( medians, numGroups, (int) ceil( ( double ) numGroups / 2 ), 0, numGroups - 1, 1 );
delete[] medians;
if( flag == 1 )
    return M;
int q = partition2( input, M, start, end );
int m = q - start + 1;
if( k == m )
    return M;
else if( k < m )
    return select( input, m - 1, k, start, q - 1, 0 );
else
    return select( input, end - q, k - m, q + 1, end, 0 );
 }

 void solution3( int input[], const int n, const int k, int output[] ) {

select( input, n, k, 0, n - 1, 0 );
for( int i = 0; i < k; i++ )
    output[i] = input[i];
 }



#endif // SOLUTIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: What is the runtime error you get?

Comment: Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: Probably an overflow.
There is at least one when initializing input arrays, eg. input1 has size 10000, and you are trying to put 100000 elements into it.
The code is too big for this question. Please narrow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building your program with address sanitizer (clang++ clock.cxx -std=c++11 -O1 -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer) reveals the problem:

```
$ ./a.out 
Hello world!
=================================================================
==8175==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x62e00000a040 at pc 0x000104dbd912 bp 0x7fff5ae43970 sp 0x7fff5ae43968
WRITE of size 4 at 0x62e00000a040 thread T0
    #0 0x104dbd911 in main clock.cxx:18
    #1 0x7fff88cd85fc in start (libdyld.dylib+0x35fc)
    #2 0x0  (<unknown module>)

0x62e00000a040 is located 0 bytes to the right of 40000-byte region [0x62e000000400,0x62e00000a040)
```

And there is your code:

```
  int* input1 = new int[10000];
  int* input2 = new int[20000];
  int* input3 = new int[40000];
  int* input4 = new int[80000];
  int* input5 = new int[100000];

  for(int i = 0; i<100000; i++)
    {
      input1[i]= rand();
      input2[i]= rand();
      input3[i]= rand();
      input4[i]= rand();
      input5[i]= rand();
    }
```

As you can see, size of input1, input2, ..., input4 is 10K, 20K, 40K, 80K elements, but in the loop we are accessing to elements out of this array so this can lead to the heap corruption.

> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

This means "memory access violation" or SEGFAULT.

Hope this will help.